# Android VideoView Buffer size

Tags: android, android-videoview, http-live-streaming

I have a android application that plays HLS (Http Live Streaming) videos using VideoView.

I am using Local http proxy for forwarding http requests from VideoView to main HLS server as my stream (transport segment) is encrypted.

`Flow of my application:`
0. Preparing VideoView with local proxy url. ex. "http:// localhost :9878/index.m3u8"
1. VideoView sends requests to my proxy for M3U8 and ts segments.
2. Proxy forwards requests for M3u8 and ts from VideoView to HLS server.
3. Proxy checks for transport stream requests and before sending response to VideoView decrypts transport stream and sends it to VideoView.
4. VideoView plays the video stream.

This is working properly but some times i get following error:
`output buffer is smaller than decoded data size Out Length`

When i get this error in logcat my video becomes garbage (green video)
I see this issue usually when video stream bitrate size increases, is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Did you find solution?